# Entity Framework .net 5.0 Cascading delete doesn't seem to work in this case

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a simple three entity relationship (EF Core 5.0), Customer has 0..n Invoices which has 0..n InvoiceLines. All running on SQL Server.

```
    namespace TestEF
    {
        public class Customer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
        }
        public class Invoice
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public Customer Customer { get; set; }
            public List<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { get; set; }
        }
        public class InvoiceLine
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
        }
        public class EFTestDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
            public DbSet<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to delete a single invoice and would expect the invoice lines to cascade delete:

```
            using var db = new EFTestDbContext();
            var customer = db.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == _customer1.Id).Include(c => c.Invoices).ThenInclude(i => i.InvoiceLines).Single();
            db.Invoices.Remove(customer.Invoices[0]);
            db.SaveChanges(true);
```

However, instead of cascading it simply sets the FK of the InvoiceLine to NULL

[image]

Where am I going wrong? I have it set up [like in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete), and it indicates in here that EF would generate appropriate SQL to do the delete of the child rows (Posts from a Blog in this case) however, I looked at the SQL from the SSMS tracer and there was only SQL to delete the Invoice not the child rows.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [Invoices]
WHERE [Id] = @p2;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

',N'@p2 int',@p2=210
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

At request of commenter: no special configuration is done in OnModelCreating, it is "out of the box"; scripts of the database tables are below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoices](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CustomerId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Invoices]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Invoices_Customers_CustomerId] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Invoices] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Invoices_Customers_CustomerId]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceLines](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LineNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceLines] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceLines]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_InvoiceLines_Invoices_InvoiceId] FOREIGN KEY([InvoiceId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Invoices] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceLines] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_InvoiceLines_Invoices_InvoiceId]
GO
```

Comment: Show us the [OnDelete(DeleteBehavior)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-6.0) configuration in OnModelCreating, for these entities. Also script your table (Script as.. Create..) and post that, so we can check no untoward differences have arisen between the database actions and what EF is configured for

Comment: @CaiusJard I think I answered your questions by adding the info to the end of the question.

Comment: Can you add the OnModelCreating for these entities? It helps us reproduce your setup

Comment: *I looked at the SQL from the SSMS tracer* - by the way it's possible to get EFC to dump what it's doing to the VS console by adding a .LogTo onto the end of your UseSqlServer call when you set up your DI

Comment: The documentation link specifies the FK must be required for cascade delete to be the inferred configuration. If the FK allows nulls, the default delete behavior is to set the FK to null. That's why people asked to see the OnModelCreating and the exact entity configuration.

Comment: OK I added the OnModelCreating, it is pretty trivial. I tried to strip the code down as much as possible to simplify it for readers.

Comment: OK, I added an explicit non nullable FK to InvoiceLines and that did create a delete cascade on that table. So that fixed my problem. If you want to do an answer to the question rather than I comment, I will accept. BTW, addint the .ToLog was a really helpful tip. Thanks to you both for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation link specifies the FK must be required for cascade delete to be the inferred configuration. If the FK allows nulls, the default delete behavior is to set the FK to null. That's why people asked to see the OnModelCreating and the exact entity configuration.